# React Native Incoming call pop up

Tags: react-native, expo, popup, incoming-call

I just want to do something like this for android devices.

When a call comes in (incoming call), a pop-up will open and the caller number will appear here, and there will be 2 buttons under it as accept and reject the call. How can I make this system in expo?
I tried almost everything but couldn’t find a way.

In addition, this pop-up should open even if the application is in the background.

If it can be done, I want to do it with expo, if not, I am waiting for your suggestions to do it with react native.

I tried almost all packages